# replace UIImageView with UIActivityIndicatorView while image loading in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

I have a `UITableViewCell` which has 2 `UIImageView` defined in xib file.
Now I came with idea to beautify the ui and I would like to change runtime the UIImageView with `UIActivityIndicatorView` until  the async response doesn't come back.

Unfortunately the `UIActivityIndicatorView` it isn't visible at all, just the complete image when finished.

Here is the relavant code part:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell =
         [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myTableCellId];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

...

```
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
```

...

```
    imageView.image=nil; // reset image as it will be retrieved asychronously

    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingActivity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [loadingActivity startAnimating];

    loadingActivity.frame = imageView.frame;
    UIView* parent = [imageView superview];
    [parent addSubview:loadingActivity];
    [parent bringSubviewToFront:loadingActivity];    

    [myObject callMyFunction:index completionBlock:^(UIImage *img) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            imageView.image=img;
            [loadingActivity stopAnimating];
            [loadingActivity removeFromSuperview];
            //DLog(@"Got image for: %@", titleLabel.text);
        });
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe stupid question on my part but, is the white spinner on top of a white background?

Comment: @Benoit yes it helps, add as answer to be accepted!!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a white spinner on a white background, it won't appear to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Set the frame and then call start Animating. Also try changing the frame you have assigned to it.

```
loadingActivity.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 20)
```

You can also set property `loadingActivity.hidesWhenStopped = YES;` instead of doing removeFromSuperview.

Comment: +1,needed gray background and is visible, on white isn't, tryed your solution too, thanks