# UIActivityIndicatorView is not visible

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have the following code part:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView  *av;
-(void) createAndShowLoadingIndicator
{
    av = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] ;
    av.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 250);
    //av.center = self.view.center;
    av.tag  = 1000;
    [self.view addSubview:av];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:av];
    [av startAnimating];
}
```

In `MyViewController.m`, I am calling with `[self createAndShowLoadingIndicator];`  and wondering why isn't visible!?   I can't see any mistakes. What is the problem, how to make it visible?

Comment: Same stuff I had, same solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17493750/529543 I can't believe it is not an auto config for that progress something..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the color to white:

```
[av setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
```

Comment: @matheszabi Remember the check!

Comment: also there is a case when is not visible: the indicator is small and centered, if there is a popup  message to ui from somewhere, that will hide it!